# Error JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un JSON como éste :

```
 {"id":"53530","name":"Bifurcadores <ul class=\'menu\' style=\'display:none\' 
 id=\'ul53530\'> <li onclick=\'pinchar(,\"Todo\")\'>
 <a href=\'#\'>LANZAR PRUEBAS TOTAL <\/a><\/li>",
 "data":{"$color":"#008000","$type":"circle"},
 "children":[{"id":"53443"

 ....etc }
```

Y al hacer ésto en Javascript:

```
 json=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(http.responseText));
```

Me sale éste error:

```
 jit.js:8795 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

¿Me podéis ayudar , por favor? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ponle un log como este: `var temp = http.responseText;
console.log(temp);` y dime que te sale, tengo sospecha que tu objecto responseText este' vacio.

Comment: Puedes intentar validar tu JSON con cualquier herramienta en linea

Comment: @Mayte ¿Podrías mostrar el código alrededor de la línea 8795?

Comment: Mira Mariano , el código de esa linea que da problema es éste : json=JSON.parse(http.responseText); (he quitado lo del stringify porque da el mismo error que con él) Muchas gracias

Comment: Probaste poniendo solo `JSON.parse(http.responseText);`?

Answer (score 1):

Tu tienes un objeto `json` donde cada objeto (me imagino) tienes un arreglo que es `children`. Cuando tu recibas el `json_encode` desde php, por ejemplo `data`

```
$.each(data, function (index) {
      console.log(index.id);
      $.each(this.children, function (children) {
         console.log(children.id);
      });
});
```

Con esto ya puedes manejar los elementos html que vienen en tu `json` y agregarlos a tu vista.

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate que tu response sea un objeto, de esta manera no ocupas hacer el JSON.parse y JSON.stringify.

```js
var obj = {"id":"53530","name":"Bifurcadores <ul class=\'menu\' style=\'display:none\' id=\'ul53530\'> <li onclick=\'pinchar(,\"Todo\")\'> <a href=\'#\'>LANZAR PRUEBAS TOTAL <\/a><\/li>"};

console.log(obj);
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

Con la parte de data y children debe ser lo mismo.
Verifica que tu response no venga vacio.

Comment: Fernando, ¿cómo podría sustituir el parse en php para que ya me venga un objeto? Muchas gracias

Comment: El JSON lo he pasado por un json_encode en php antes de mandárselo al js

Comment: @Mayte si en PHP tienes un array, lo conviertes a JSON simplemente con algo como: `$arrJson=json_encode($arrPhp);` luego mandas `$arrJson` a Javascript... si lo que tienes en PHP no es un array, sino una cadena, tendrías que construir tu json de forma manual y pasarla a js o pasar la cadena a js y hacer que éste cree el json de lado del cliente a partir de la cadena que recibe.  http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que para transmitir el `Json` lo debes hacer como una cadena.

JSON es un formato (ahora) estándar para transmitir objetos de un sistema a otro que al ser simple permite que cualquier lenguaje pueda construir un objeto a partir del texto transmitido, por lo tanto si vas a hacer comunicación de un servidor PHP a un script JS el servidor debe transmitir [`json_encode($obj)`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) y el script debe procesar [`JSON.parse(objString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse); si fuera al revés, el script debe enviar [`JSON.stringify(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) y el server debe parsear con [`json_decode($_POST["obj"])`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Es correcto lo que mencionás, pero ¿podrías explicar en particular cómo está relacionado al error de la pregunta y qué es lo que se está realizando que debería modificarse?

Comment: El error que menciona me indica que el objeto no está bien _parseado_, por eso el énfasis en ello en ambos lados.